# Ubuntu doesn't ask for password after booting

Tags: password

I'm using Ubuntu 15.04 and already changed the settings refered to password.
But my PC doesn't ask for any when I start it. There is only my user available.

Answer (score 1):

Upon Installation you may have mistakenly checked the [do not require password] option. Go into your settings and select [require my password]. That should fix it XD!

Comment: Nope. Config in Settings is okay, I'm demanding requisition of password.

Comment: Hmm that's odd have you tried resetting your password via command line?